# Provide the path to ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

What should be the correct path to the `servlet-context.xml` in 
`ApplicationContext contex = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("???");`

This is path in properties `servlet-context.xml`: `/HealthHelperWeb/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml`

[image]

Comment: `servlet-context.xml` where is it present relative to your runtime classpath ?

Comment: I am a novice , how can I check it?

Comment: how do you launch the app, where does this file gets placed once you start the app ?

Comment: http://zapodaj.net/a80ef580cecf1.png.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using maven, you could place this xml file in `src/main/resources` directory and refer it by

```
ApplicationContext contex = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/servlet-context.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks moved it to the META -INF and is ok

Comment: better place is resources for maven projects, it needs to be available during runtime in classpath at relative path specified, feel free to mark it as accepted